# Consulta API Twitter - R Studio

Tags: r, twitter

Estoy haciendo una investigación educativa para la universidad, y trato de hacer un analisis de sentimiento y descriptivo usando el paquete rtweet (v1), pero me encuentro con la siguiente situación

He creado la siguiente consulta

```
data <- search_tweets2(q, n = 400,
                      include_rts = FALSE,
                      parse = TRUE,
                      verbose = TRUE)
```

pero una vez se completa la busqueda trae las siguientes columnas, la cual no incluyen el nombre de usuario:

```
 [1] "created_at"                    "id"                           
 [3] "id_str"                        "full_text"                    
 [5] "truncated"                     "display_text_range"           
 [7] "entities"                      "metadata"                     
 [9] "source"                        "in_reply_to_status_id"        
[11] "in_reply_to_status_id_str"     "in_reply_to_user_id"          
[13] "in_reply_to_user_id_str"       "in_reply_to_screen_name"      
[15] "geo"                           "coordinates"                  
[17] "place"                         "contributors"                 
[19] "is_quote_status"               "retweet_count"                
[21] "favorite_count"                "favorited"                    
[23] "retweeted"                     "possibly_sensitive"           
[25] "lang"                          "quoted_status_id"             
[27] "quoted_status_id_str"          "quoted_status"                
[29] "text"                          "favorited_by"                 
[31] "scopes"                        "display_text_width"           
[33] "retweeted_status"              "quoted_status_permalink"      
[35] "quote_count"                   "timestamp_ms"                 
[37] "reply_count"                   "filter_level"                 
[39] "query"                         "withheld_scope"               
[41] "withheld_copyright"            "withheld_in_countries"        
[43] "possibly_sensitive_appealable"
```

Por lo que me veo obligado a usar la formula para consultar los usuarios:  `u <- users_data(data)` y esta me trae los usuarios y nombres en un objeto diferente.

No pude encontrar la manera de unir ambos objetos dado que no tienen relacion alguna mas que la columna `id_str` que de igual manera no coinciden las informacion .

¿Hay alguna manera de obtener dichos tweets de un hashtag que incluya el nombre de usuario?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Ola Johan. Los datasets se corresponden fila por fila. Es más , el data.frame "data" tiene un atributo "users" que almacena los usuairios (puedes obtenerlo mediante `attr(data, "users")`) que es de donde la función users_data los extrae.
Entonces es cuestion de hacer `cbind(data, users_data(data))`

Comment: ¡Eres un crack! @RicVillalba Esto me ha ayudado bastante para continuar mi analisis. Muchas gracias por compartir este conocimiento.